# Is there a way to write two (or more) dataframes to one excel spreadsheet?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

it would help me produce output that was a lot neater and a little more 'human-like' if I could use pandas and xlsxwriter in a way that would stack two dataframes, one on top of the other, on the same sheet of the Excel spreadsheet I am outputting.

Pls note the data of the two dataframes is related but different, one being a summary of the other.

Is there a neat way I can just take my dataframe and my summary dataframe and stack them on the same sheet?

Comment: What do you mean *"on top of"*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's very much possible.

You will have to build the excel file using xlsxwriter and keep track of the current cell as you write.

Here is some pseudo code/syntax (I use xlsxwriter as an extension of Pandas):

```
wb = pd.ExcelWriter(file)
tab = wb.sheets["My Tab"]
row, column = 9, 1
df1.to_excel(wb, tab, header=False, startrow=row, startcol=column, index=False)
row += 4
column = 1
df2.to_excel(wb, tab, header=False, startrow=row, startcol=column, index=False)
```

I am missing some parts in here, but all I really wanted to do was illustrate the point.

I've built out a flimsy [Report Class](https://github.com/kennes913/ezpdreports/blob/master/report_class.py) to do this for me. You can see some of my syntax in the `.write_tab` method.